# Surface Area of a Truncated Right Prism

Tags: geometry

I was studying for exams when I stumbled across this question.

> A block of earth in the form of truncated right prism has a square base with 12 centimeter edges. Two adjacent lateral edges are each 20 centimeter long and the other two lateral edges are each 14 centimeter long. Find the total surface area of the block.

My work:

This is how I imagined the problem:

[image]

From here, I'm stuck.

I do know there are six areas found. I can find the area of the base, but I couldn't find the other 5 areas, in which two of those areas (the front and the back) has angled upper base. I don't know how to get those areas that involve angled upper bases.

How do you get the surface area of the above problem?

Comment: Are the faces that have two equal sides trapezia? That is, are their other two edges parallel?

Comment: Your drawing is not a truncated prism. A [right prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_(geometry)) with a square base is basically a rectangular block.

Comment: Since it is a right prism the faces are perpendicular to the base not slanted.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis  oh gosh.......why do I mistake pyramids for prismsXD

Comment: @ajotatxe my bad....I mistake pyramids for prisms

Comment: I think the text is right: it must be a truncated right prism, otherwise the data wouldn't be enough to compute area. But you should improve your diagram: lateral edges are perpendicular to the base. The answer, however, is not difficult: all faces are rectangles, after all.